# Print currently showing activity

Tags: android

I'm getting back into Android development and have been missing one amazing tool from iOS: Chisel. It allowed me to print out all the views on screen as well as to print out a list of the current stack of view controllers, which allowed me to easily identify which view controller a screen belonged to.

Is there any way to do this in Android? I'd love to be able to print out every view on the screen as well as to print out the activities on the stack, but if I can only print out the activity stack that would be OK. But printing the activity stack is something I'm desperately missing!

Comment: There may be stuff in `adb shell dumpsys` that contains what you want for the task stack. In general, the stack of activities in a task spans apps and processes, which makes it more sensitive and problematic than you may be thinking. In terms of the views, use Hierarchy View (e.g., Android Device Monitor from Android Studio), or use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio 2.2+.